# ELF symbol visibility

Tags: shared-libraries, visibility, symbols, elf

Lets say I define an api (sym1) in file spec_a.h
There is an implementation of this api in lib_imp1.so.
I can have an application that dlopen's this shared library, dlsym() sym1 and invoke it. Is it possible for the application to dlopen() some other shared library with sym1 as undefined and it gets resolved to sym1 in lib_imp1.so?
If so, how do we do it?

If it is possible, then we can have two implementations, lib_imp1.so and lib_imp2.so with both having two different addresses for the same symbol sym1.
If the application loads another shared library with unresolved sym1, can we have any control on which sym1 (lib_imp1.so or lib_imp2.so) it gets resolved to?

While generating lib_imp1.so, can we say that while we want sym1 to be exported, we do not want any unresolved symbol to be resolved to it? (sort of controlled export??)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I can have an application that dlopen's this shared library, dlsym() sym1 and invoke it. Is it possible for the application to dlopen() some other shared library with sym1 as undefined and it gets resolved to sym1 in lib_imp1.so?

Yes: if the first `dlopen` uses `RTLD_GLOBAL`, then all symbols exported from `lib_imp1.so` (including `sym1`) are entered into the global scope, and become visible to other libraries loaded later.

> If it is possible, then we can have two implementations, lib_imp1.so and lib_imp2.so with both having two different addresses for the same symbol sym1.

Yes. This is ill-advised.

> If the application loads another shared library with unresolved sym1, can we have any control on which sym1 (lib_imp1.so or lib_imp2.so) it gets resolved to?

No. Assuming you `dlopen`ed both `lib_imp1.so` and `lib_imp2.so` with `RTLD_GLOBAL`, any subsequent library will always bind to `sym1` from the first `dlopen`ed library that provides it (i.e. it will resolve to `lib_imp1.so` definition).

Further, if `lib_imp1.so` also exports `sym2`, and anything in `lib_imp2.so` calls `sym2`, that symbol would *also* resolve to the definition inside `lib_imp1.so` (unless you take special care and use `-Bsymbolic`).

The end result is that UNIX `.so` libraries behave much like archive libraries would, and not like windows `DLL`s. That makes having two separate implementations that export the same interface largely non-workable in a single process.

> While generating lib_imp1.so, can we say that while we want sym1 to be exported, we do not want any unresolved symbol to be resolved to it?

The `dlsym` uses *exactly* the same resolution process. If you make the symbol not available for anything to resolve to it, `dlsym` will not find it either. Conversely, exporting symbol means exactly "make it available for resolution" (by either `dlopen` or just regular unresolved dependency resolution).